# Azure CLI "--query" in powershell return back String type instead of boolean?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I'm running the following PowerShell azure cli query to check whether a KV resource exists or not. But seems like the query result is string "false" instead of boolean false. The string "false" will cause an error if I'm doing `if ($result)` later on as it will always be true.

Wondering is this the expected return type of all azure cli query or I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Az CLI is not PowerShell CmdLet and it just returns untyped string-based value through STDOUT.

Use Azure PowerShell CmdLets or convert returned value with ConvertFrom-JSON:

> `(az keyvault list | ConvertFrom-Json) | Filter/Select/etc`